# Batch if exists xcopy and create new folder for file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, xcopy

My aim is to locate files on a specified directory copy them and move them to another directory but create a new folder for the files I wish to move.

To give some additional information I am moving a large number of wav files from one server to another server.

Code I have found for this:

```
If exist \\%DIR%\%Folder%\123456789.wav xcopy \\%DIR%\%Folder%\123456789.wav D:\%New Folder%\ /y
```

So will this find the files I want, copy it and then paste into new directory with my %New Folder% (the folder will not exist and I wish this command to create it before pasting the wav file.

Comment: You don't really need to check if the file exists, if it doesn't then it cannot be copied. To compensate for the error message from the file not existing, you can redirect the message to the `NUL` using `2>Nul`: `XCopy \\%DIR%\%Folder%\123456789.wav D:\%New Folder%\ /Y 2>Nul`. You may also need to use doublequotes too around the paths, to protect spaces etc.

Answer (score 1):

`xcopy` will create the directory structure for you, if it does not yet exist, if you have the trailing backslash.

```
@echo off
set "NewFolder=D:\Some Destination\folder\"
set "DIR=someserver\Some Source folder"
set "Folder=Another Folder"
If exist "\\%DIR%\%Folder%\123456789.wav" (
      xcopy "\\%DIR%\%Folder%\123456789.wav" "%NewFolder%" /y
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No it won't.  You have not defined your variables dir, folder, and new folder.
I am going to answer the question as if you are using windows and you want a batch file.

Amend your question after reading:

[Copy files on a network:] [2](https://www.google.com/search?ei=18DaXJ3PEpC8sAW3grCIBw&q=windows+10+batch+unc)

[How to write a windows batch file] [3](https://www.google.com/search?ei=2sDaXNXPKsWUsgXE3a_IBg&q=how+to+write+a+windows+batch+file)

[How to use FOR] [5](https://www.google.com/search?ei=VsbaXJn4PMKAtgXJkb6QBA&q=windows+10+batch+for)

[How to use ROBOCOPY] [4](https://www.google.com/search?ei=dcHaXJG2No_AsAXQwLqQDQ&q=how+to+use+robocopy)

a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set dir=??????????
set folder=????????????
set "new folder=??????????"
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b "%dir%\%folder%\*.wav"') do %systemroot%\system32\xcopy.exe /sy "%%F" "d:\%new folder%\"
exit /b
```

Put the batch file in the root folder of the volume where the .wav files are located and run it.

If could be as simple as a windows shortcut:
`%systemroot%\system32\xcopy.exe /sy *.wav "d:\new folder\"`
Copy all .wav files in folder and subfolders, create new folder w/o prompt, do not prompt before overwriting.

But since you are copying files on a network it is more complicated and since you've given so little information it is just a shot in the dark.

More info:

xcopy /?

set /? (define variables)

for /?

dir /? (find the files)

cmd /?

Comment: I recommend the usage of `%SystemRoot%` instead of `%windir%`. The usage of environment variable `windir` is deprecated since Windows NT4. `windir` is a __system__ environment variable which is by default defined, but can be deleted from list of __system__ environment variables in which case it does not longer exist for any application making use of it after restart of Windows at the latest. `SystemRoot` is always defined by Windows and the only method existing to have it not defined is explicitly deleting it in a script/application.

Comment: PS: After deletion of environment variable `windir` from list of __system__ variables, it is no longer possible on Windows 7 to click on *Advanced system settings* in __Control Panel - System__. The result is the error message: *Windows cannot find '%windir%\system32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.* It is very strange that a user with local administrator privileges can delete deprecated environment variable `windir` while Windows itself makes use of `windir` instead of `SystemRoot` in its executables and libraries. What a shame for MS.

Comment: @mofi.  Does Beej comment sound reasonable to you: "fun fact - (on Windows 10 1809) %windir% is still so essential that you can't run anything elevated without it... which means YOU CAN'T ACTUALLY PUT IT BACK because hitting the environment variable registry apparently requires elevation".

Comment: Well, I have seen `windir` environment variable always in __system__ variables list, but never touched it until yesterday as I deleted this __system__ environment variable and checked if Windows defines it nevertheless on starting a new command process. It does not while `SystemRoot` is always defined on starting a new command process from Windows desktop. Then I wanted to define `windir` again as I know that many batch files and also applications and libraries still make use of it and was really shocked to see that Windows itself still uses it.

Comment: However, it was absolutely no problem for me to run in a cmd window as administrator `%SystemRoot%\system32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe` and add again environment variable `windir` to __system__ environment variables list. I was really surprised that a still so important environment variable is not predefined by Windows automatically like `SystemRoot`, `SystemDrive` and a lot more not listed in __user__ or __system__ variables list, but defined by default as it can be seen on running `set` in a cmd window. That's really a shame for Microsoft in my opinion.